# ¿Cómo busco la posición de una matriz donde se un número que sea divisor de otro?

Tags: c++

Esto es lo que tengo pero no me envia como tal la posición por ejemplo este es el mensaje fila: 181904, columna: 1334823597.

```
void halla_divisor(int &fila, int &columna, int mat[20][20], int n){

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if((i>j) && (mat[i][j] % 84 == 0)){
                fila = i;
                columna =  j;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero sería inicializar los valores de `fila` y `columna` para detectar casos en los que no haya **ninguna celda** que coincida con la búsqueda:

```
void halla_divisor(int &fila, int &columna, int mat[20][20], int n)
{
  fila = -1;
  columna = -1;

  // ...
}
```

Por otro lado, fíjate que tu ahora mismo tienes la siguiente condición:

```
if((i>j) && (mat[i][j] % 84 == 0)){
```

Es decir, que la fila debe ser mayor que la columna y que el valor de la celda debe ser divisible por 84. Entiendo que la comparación de la fila con la columna sobra, lo que simplifica un poco la línea:

```
if(mat[i][j] % 84 == 0)
{
  // ...
}
```

Finalmente, una vez que encuentras una celda que cumple con los parámetros de búsqueda, carece de sentido seguir buscando... es tiempo perdido. Es preferible salir de la función una vez tenemos el resultado buscado:

```
if(mat[i][j] % 84 == 0)
{
  // ...
  return;
}
```

Por otro lado, dado que `fila` y `columna` son valores de salida, lo suyo sería devolverlos vía `return`. Para ello se podría usar una `std::pair`:

```
std::pair<int, int> halla_divisor(int mat[20][20], int n)
{
  for( int i=0; i<n; i++ )
  {
    for( int j=0; j<n; j++ )
    {
      if( mat[i][j] % 84 == 0 )
      {
        return {i, j};
      }
    }
  }

  return {-1, -1};
}
```

Para *desarmar* la pareja de valores puedes usar la función `std::tie`:

```
// C++98
std::pair<int, int> resultado = halla_divisor(mat, 10);
int fila = resultado.first;
int columna = resultado.second;

// C++11
int fila, columna;
std::tie(fila, columna) = halla_divisor(mat, 10);

// C++17
auto [fila, columna] = halla_divisor(mat, 10);
```

Una ventaja de usar el `return` para la devolución de valores es que no te obliga a crear variables que no te interesan. Por ejemplo, si solo te interesase conocer la fila podrías descartar facilmente la columna:

```
int fila;
std::tie(fila, std::ignore) = halla_divisor(mat, 10);
//             ~~~~~~~~~~~ Ignoramos el valor de la columna
```

Comment: `mat[i][j] % 84 == ` contará `0` como divisor de `84`, no se si es lo que se busca.

Answer (score 0):

Si te está devolviendo valores "*extraños*" en la operación, puede ser porque `fila` y `columna` no han sido inicializadas y nunca son actualizadas:

```
int main()
{
    int f, c; // NO INICIALIZADAS
    int matriz[20][20] { /* valores */ };

    halla_divisor(f, c, matriz, 20);
    std::cout << "Divisor de 84 en " << f << " x " << c << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Respecto a que `fila` y `columna` no han sido actualizadas, puede ser porque no haya encontrado ningún múltiplo de 84, o porque no lo haya o porque la comparación es incorrecta:

```
if((i>j) && (mat[i][j] % 84 == 0)
```

No necesitas comparar `i` con `j` para saber si `mat[i][j]` es múltiplo de 84, con esto es suficiente:

```
if (!(mat[i][j] % 84))
```

En C++ los enteros se convierten implícitamente a valores booleanos siendo `false` el valor `0` y `true` cualquier otro valor, así que el número será múltiplo de 84 cuando la expresión `mat[i][j] % 84` sea cero (`false`), por eso le damos la vuelta negando la expresión con `!`, cuidado: esto contará `0` como divisor de `84`, no se si es un comportamiento deseado.

---

No he podido evitar observar que pasas a la función `halla_divisor` el tamaño de la matriz como argumento, puedes evitarte esa molestia pasando la matriz por referencia:

```
void halla_divisor(int &fila, int &columna, int (&mat)[20][20])
//                                              ^^^^^^ <--- Matriz 20×20 pasada por referencia
```

Esto tiene la ventaja de que no permite pasar matrices de un tamaño distinto al especificado:

```
int main()
{
    int f = 0, c = 0;
    int matriz[10][10] { /* valores */ };

    halla_divisor(f, c, matriz); // Error ¡'matriz' no es int[20][20]!
    std::cout << "Divisor de 84 en " << f << " x " << c << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Pero además te permite usar el bucle `for` de rango en el cuerpo de la función:

```
void halla_divisor(int &fila, int &columna, int (&mat)[20][20]){
    fila = 0;
    for (const auto &f : mat) {
        columna = 0;
        for (const auto &valor : f) {
            if (!(valor % 84)) {
                return;
            }
            ++columna;
        }
        ++fila;
    }
}
```

Esta nueva implementación tiene en cuenta el problema de la inicialización (inicializa los argumentos en la propia función) pero no tiene en cuenta el caso de no encontrar ningún divisor.

En caso de no encontrar ningún divisor, `fila`  y `columna` tendrán valor `21` pero podemos hacer que la función informe de si la búsqueda dio resultado sin comprobar los valores de `fila`  y `columna`:

```
bool halla_divisor(int &fila, int &columna, int (&mat)[20][20]){
    fila = 0;
    for (const auto &f : mat) {
        columna = 0;
        for (const auto &valor : f) {
            if (!(valor % 84)) {
                return true;
            }
            ++columna;
        }
        ++fila;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Con esto tu código [podría parecerse a](https://tio.run/##7VTRTsIwFH2mX3HFCFtWE4agONAnH/0DMaaUTpt0Lek6YiT79nlLZ3Dqq2@7y5Kec8897Zrs8N3ukiumX5vmXGquqq2AlTSls4IV94RsjFHwxpRiL1u5l6WxkdQORrlUjMJxyY2qCt2iaFQwFz9NJ8/@jQ8EsLwY7mCyDMhYiLjRpQNWOYNekIGfgqD21Xqehv4c3DOFVAb591FfMofoLArtC1jM4p8CX1a4ympwthLLTrPuoCRpD3MSnQRJ4r8tdALbuuZMlWhbE@JvpWBSRzE5kIFHm6/rOaR0Sq/ojM7pNb2hC3pLp0ggg9ScpmlKu0@v7tW9@t/V9TL8qDkF7peYJt0I9A0Kmzgmg0HptlnGTeVgtYLhQ1AAxuhiBkLD0NN5kh678B4wD3i81mP0FxgVv4wemc9EKz9AG4xD7aTQAtoDiDJssNZDnG8jB5OybppP):

```
#include <iostream>

bool halla_divisor(int &fila, int &columna, int (&mat)[20][20]){
    fila = 0;
    for (const auto &f : mat) {
        columna = 0;
        for (const auto &valor : f) {
            if (!(valor % 84)) {
                return true;
            }
            ++columna;
        }
        ++fila;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    int b[20][20]{ /* valores */ };
    int f, c;
    if (halla_divisor(f, c, b))
        std::cout << "Divisor de 84 en " << f+1 << " x " << c+1 << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "La matriz no contiene divisores de 84\n";
    return 0;
}
```